# How to convert char/* to wchar_t/* ---but

Tags: c++

I'm converting an (rather)old C code into VS2010. Everything works fine when I compile program with multibyte option but I have to convert it into UNICODE.

I'm getting a lot of error messages related with string conversation (but it is not strange).
My problem is related with the fact that I have to work with wchar strings (because of UNICODE) but I also have to retain standard char values ( Program needs to write data into file with standard ascii code).

To be more clear, UNICODE is needed for working with Windows but files must be saved into ascii format. I receive errors on many places and that's why I've decided to put that question here.

May somoene suggest what's the best practice for this kind of problem?

Thank you in advance!

edit:

well , I'm not an expert for C/C++, this is my first large project. I've tried your suggestion from the first answer like this:                                                                    }

```
    { 
TCHAR* strz1=_T("%u blocks converted.");
      if (n>0) 
      {
      sprintf(str,strz1,n)
      }
      else
      TCHAR* strz2=_T("No blocks found!"); 
      sprintf(str,strz2);
      TCHAR* strz3=_T("Status");
      MessageBoxW(hwnd,str,strz3,MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
      return(fe);
    }
```

Im getting famous errors:

error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'

error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [32]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: Best practice for your scenario ("I have errors. I won't tell you what they are") is to fix the problem. I won't tell you how.

Comment: Use `UNICODE`, but call functions that you need to use ASCII in like `MessageBoxA`, instead of `MessageBoxW` or `MessageBox`. Use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert the string. I'm not sure that's all without an example though.

Comment: So your question is how to convert between ASCII and Unicode? Did you try googling?

Comment: A few things: Firstly, your `else` should immediately follow your `if` (you might want braces there). Second, you should use `_vsprintf` or whatever the name was with `TCHAR`. Third, in order to explicitly use `MessageBoxW`, you should be converting the arguments to wide strings using something like `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: Chris.. I know for IF/ELSE, it isn't a problem. but, can you tell me what command to use instead of sprintf?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MFC, then check these conversion macros for CString: [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

That way you can export your files with UTF-8 and read them from UTF-8 back to UTF-16, which is the natural way of storing wchar_s. That way your application can use UNICODE and still export in ASCII (UTF-8 is backward compatible with ASCII).